# Swift, interfaces and abstract classes

Tags: swift, interface, polymorphism, protocols, abstract

I need to create an interface or abstract class java style.
Money is a protocol, the equivalent Java interface.

Implement the interface (protocol) in the Euro class, but it gives me error in the function times.

In function times I use polymorphism and return a Money because Euro implements the Money interface (protocol), but i have a error: "Use of undeclared type 'Money'. Why?

```
protocol Money {
    var amount: Int {get set}
    func times(multiplier: Int) -> Money
    init (amount: Int)
}

class Euro : NSObject, Money {
    internal var amount: Int

    required init(amount: Int) {
        self.amount = amount
    }

    func times(multiplier: Int) -> Money {
        return Euro(amount: self.amount * multiplier)
    }

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return self.amount == (object as! Euro).amount
    }
}
```

Comment: What line has the error exactly?  It all works for me in Playground.

Comment: protocols should have delegate set in the implementation class , but there seems no delegate set in your class?

Comment: I rewrite the Euro Class and I dont have errors, but now, my Test dont run. I cant create a simple object in test.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me in Swift 2 Xcode 7.0 beta 4 if, for example, I create an instance of `Euro` and then call its `.times` method. Eg:

```
var xEuro = Euro(amount: 10)
print(xEuro.times(2).amount)
```

Comment: I rewrite the code, and work... I´m confused.... but now i dont create a simple Euro object in Tests. For example  func testNotNil() {
        var euro: Euro = Euro (amount: 3)
        XCTAssertNotNil(euro, "The object not be nil")
    }   The error is in the line var euro: Euro = Euro(amount: 3) and say "Use of undeciared type 'Euro'

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the solution... 
http://roadfiresoftware.com/2014/06/unit-testing-with-swift/

To test a Swift class with XCTest, you need to add that class to the test target. (Hopefully this is a temporary hack, but it’s been this way since Swift was in beta. I’m not holding my breath.) So, with your class selected and displayed in the editor, look at the Target Membership section in the File Inspector (the right pane) to make sure that both the app target and the test target are selected.

Comment: In Swift 2 there is [`@testable`](http://natashatherobot.com/swift-2-xcode-7-unit-testing-access/)